# Mass Upload In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to upload product using mass upload in magento. There is no error while uploading the csv file. but their is no product uploaded. here is my screen shot

[This is the first image. I checked first if it is valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6zni.jpg)

[The message Said that it was successfully uploaded. When i check the product their is no product uploaded. Please help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTBTI.jpg)

Comment: Try cleaning Cache and Reindex data.

Comment: Nothing Change. I try to change the encoded to UTF-8 but it doesnt work.
i try to upload.